# How do you build a Q&A site?

Tags: open-source, sites

Is there an open source platform that allows a developer to quickly build a Q&A site? For example, was StackOverflow built from the ground up or did it leverage an existing platform?

Comment: What platform? Please specify

Comment: Do you want (1) an general QA site with forums, articles and such or (2) an special QA site for a particular project. In case of (2) you could use Maven and Sonar to get a nice website with all kind of QA reports...

Answer (score 3):

As far as I know Stackoverflow was built from scratch using .net

Here is a presentation at Google that explains the ideas behind stack overflow

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NWHfY_lvKIQ

There was a person on SO some time ago who wrote a question, asking a similar question and answered it saying that he had built something like SO and made it open source - it was/is called Stacked.

http://ra-ajax.org/stacked-an-open-source-implementation-of-stackoverflow-com.blog

Answer (score 3):

There is open source Q&A platform available at http://www.osqa.net/ Its look and feel is pretty similar to stackexchange sites.

In their own words:

> OSQA is the free, open source Q&A system you've been waiting for. Your
>   OSQA site is more than just an FAQ page, it is a full-featured Q&A
>   community. Users earn points and badges for useful participation, and
>   everyone in the community wins.

Answer (score 0):

SO was built from scratch in .net. The guys have discussed releasing the SO code as open source, but have not come to a decision yet. (see here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7335/the-stackoverflow-source-code and here https://stackoverflow.fogbugz.com/default.asp?W4331).

There are various open source copies around you could look at. Ankur mentioned one. There is also cnprog (here http://code.google.com/p/cnprog/)

Answer (score 0):

[DotNetNuke](http://www.dotnetnuke.com) is great.  It has a whole lot of modules that could be used or adapted to do a Q&A.  And since it is ubiquitous, there are lots of resources (including SO) where you can get help.

Answer (score 0):

There is an open source Q&A platform that looks quite promising, and it's called Shapado. There's a paid version as well, but the code, which is built in ruby, mongomapper and mongodb, is available on Gitorious:
https://gitorious.org/shapado

It lacks, however, some of the richer features of Stack Overflow that enable reputation building and surfacing of best content. Which you can, no doubt, build yourself.